# Does a Web Agency have the right to add its logo in material produced for a client?

Tags: client-relations

My company hired a web agency to build the company's website and the online presence through social media.

The first video that the web agency made (A video previously produced by the company but re adapted for use on social media by the web agency) had the logo of the agency at the end of the video and not in a very discrete way. Wen we talked to the agency to say that we'd prefer if they didn't add the logo at the end of videos, they refused saying that the agency should be the "mirror of the company" and that keeping their logo is a sign of "mutual gratitude" (not sure what that means).

Do web agencies have the "right" to add their logo in clients material? Or is it even a *convention* for companies to let their web agencies add their logos?

Answer (score 2):

If it's in the contract, it's in the contract. But it's not convention for them to include their logo in a video made for your company, and usually products like a video will take a time or two of revisions between them and your company to get everything the way you want it to be (again, this should be in the contract) so you should be okay requesting a change after they "complete" it. It seems like this isn't the type of company you want to be working with in the future though.

More information about the content of the video would help us give a more specific answer.